# Will WebView cache persist between application runs?

Tags: android

I have a WebView. I'm not quite sure how caching works for it. Ideally I'd like to load a webpage from the network once (images included), then from then on only ever load it from the local cache. I'm not sure if we have this level of control over webview. Will it at some point just auto-clear the cache? How could I tell? I need to be sure that it's really keeping the page cached between different runs of my application.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

the cache modes there don't seem to specify if the cache persists between runs of the application or not?

Thanks

Comment: The default Android browser doesn't support this, so I guess WebView itself won't support this neither.

Though I don't know for sure.

If it's not kept, you should download the webpage and all resources yourself (or request them from the webview, when it's active) and save them in your apk's directory.

Comment: There is an option you can specify to [only load from cache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_CACHE_ONLY), so I guess that it will persist. But I can't find any docs on it...!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `cache` folder in your apk's data directory

in a command prompt run

```
adb shell
#cd /data/data/yourpackage
#ls
<<you should see a cache directory>>
```